# alternative when an older browser does not accept jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, cross-browser

I have just been altered to the fact that a user of my website is using a very old browser which does not run jquery (in this case Safari 1.x) and as a result can not access the login panel which uses jquery's slideToggle function.

Can anyone think of a fix which detects whether a browser is able to use jquery - and if not make that link go to a different page rather than showing the login panel?

Comment: Does it work with no script on at all or is it that it does enough javascript to prevent access to the login panel?

Comment: I see what you mean, but that won't work because the user has javascript enabled, so the browser will ignore the noscript stuff

Comment: Would using an alternative library be acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the plain HTML source code for the the href= of the login link, set that to a plain HTML login page.

Using jQuery, attach the click handler to the link, if this part fails, thats ok, the browser will just follow the href in the link to the plain login page, allowing your old-browser-user to login still.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#login_link_id').click(function(){
    // Your code here
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You could a little conditional check like

```
if(!'jQuery' in window) {
    // jQuery is not available
}
```

or, if Safari 1.x doesn't know about the `IN` operator (I'm not sure) use

```
if(!window.jQuery) {
}
```

Comment: I went with the second of these options and it seems to work... thanks

Comment: I take this back... sorry... at the time, the only way I could test this was to remove the jquery pack and that worked, but it seems that if the jquery pack is there and the user uses an old version of IE or Safari then this fix does nothing.

Answer (score 4):

I think there are alternative answers to this, but for me, I would have to weigh up the time it will take you to support his obsolete browser (I'm sure there may be other things inside the site), versus the payback to you...

Comment: +1.  How much is this user actually worth to you?  Are you risking losing hundreds or thousands of dollars by not supporting ancient browsers?  I'd not fix it just based on principle.

Comment: Each user could potentially cost tens of thousands of dollars if they are unable to log in. And if their experience is not a good one, they will not recommend the site to others - and so the chain continues.

Answer (score 1):

If you use javascript/jQuery you should ALWAYS ensure your site works perfectly without it.  In this case if you have a login popup box; you probably assign a click event assigned after the DOM has loaded.

What you should do is ensure that if jQuery isn't present the link loads a "normal" login webpage as opposed to the popupbox.  I use something similar to this:

```
<a href="/login.html" id="loginlink">Log in</a>
<script>
    if(!'jQuery' in window) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //assign on click event to loginlink
        });
    }
</script>
```

If jQuery doesn't exist then `login.html` will be opened normally.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, seriously?! Safari 1.x?? Anyhow, try this...

```
var isJQSupported = false;

$(function() { //shorthand for document.ready

  isJQSupported = true;

  //your usual code


});

if (!isJQSupported) {

  window.location = "http://www.apple.com/safari/download/";

}
```

Comment: This won't work. The callback you pass to `$()` is not guaranteed to run immediately (like if the DOM's not ready) and so the condition at the end (`if (!isJQSupported)`) might be met even if jQuery is supported.

Comment: this would throw an exception, `Reference error` (unless Safari 1 magic)

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like safari 1.X has problems with jQuery internally. Which means simple checks like whether $ exists in the global space or whether $(function) does anything are not going to help.

The most likely root cause will be that javascript throws an error in loading of jQuery itself which will then stop the rest of your javascript code from execution.

There are four viable options here.

- Either make the website work with noscript. Replace your login control with pure HTML and postbacks and ask the user to turn javascript off. This option is useful since you won't be fixing the issue for safari 1.x problems specifically.
- You can make javascript check for safari 1.X and other non-supported browsers and only load jQuery through script tag injection or ajax if your user is using a supported browser. If the user is using a browser not compatible with jQuery then you can instead use plain javascript.
- Get a copy of safari 1.x and see why jQuery breaks. Then fix it and ask for it to pulled into the release of jQuery 1.5. This relies on the fix being something that does can be done without hacking and that the jQuery team agrees is worth adding in.
- Ask the user to use a compliant browser.

There might be some more options. I would personally lean towards asking the user to use a compliant browser because supporting Safari 1.x is ridiculous.

Comment: I would like to be able to test in Safari 1.x but that would mean I'd have to uninstall the latest Safari. I'm sure everyone would agree that would be silly!

Comment: If you want to solve a bug in Safari 1.x you need to reproduce, test and debug it in Safari 1.x. If you don't want to do that then tell the user Safari 1.x is not supported. Either test and fix it for Safari 1.x or make it work with noscript on.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a case where [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) is needed.

You have to do multiple checks

1. see if $ exists
2. see if $.fn exists
3. [not sure if needed] check if $.support is a function
4. check for feature support as needed with $.support() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

At the end of the check, when jQuery reports that features you need are present - the rest of the script can run.

If you're not sure which features mentioned in the support you use, then this might need a single test on Safari 1.x to see what are the values returned by $.support(), but that is what your nasty old-browser-user can do for you (if you prepare code and publish) and report the resulting text. Then you compare the list with other [old] browsers that are accessible and determine features that are required.

The easy way would be to require everything and cancel all scripts if suport for any feature is missing. This will also rule out IE6 and IE7 and opera below 9.something and firefox below 2.0 or including - I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use a server side language to detect if it's the old safari based on user-agent and load a different javascript file